# rad window showing scroll

Tags: asp.net, css, iframe, telerik, radwindow

I am using rad window to open a dialog which contains a div and inside that div there is a table in which i am showing some comments i have to provide the scrollable paging for the div so i have added some css property for it.

Now the problem is the rad window is also showing scroll that is creating confusion for the user due to two scrolls being shown how to remove the scroll.

The HTML markup of the page

```
<div class="div_Custom ">
            <table class="tb_Custom">
            </table>
        </div
```

Css class

```
.div_custom

 {
border:2px solid #E3E3E3;
margin:0 20px;
max-height:250px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

So what should i do to remove the scroll

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Autosize feature of the RadWindow - [demo for autosize](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/autosize/defaultcs.aspx). Alternatively, you can set a fixed width/height for your div and the RadWindow so you are sure that the window will be big enough and the div will not grow past that size.